# Problems inserting charCodes into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a bit maddening.  New to javascript and I haven't coded in ages.  I am looking to convert a string of characters into their charCodes and dump them into an array.  This is the current code:

```
function fillArray(str) {
var arr=[];

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    arr.push(str.charCodeAt(str.charAt(i)));
  }

  return arr;
}
```

What ends up happening is if I sent it a string like "abcd", it will return [97,97,97,97].  Even though the charAt(i) should be iterating through, the array only seems to be formed by looking at the first character in the string only.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

`charCodeAt` takes the index of the character you want, not the actual character; so just remove the `charAt` part:

```
arr.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
```

Comment: but why he is getting 97 all time

Comment: @Mahi because he's passing the return value from `.charAt()` as the **index** to be used by `.charCodeAt()`.  It'll generally evaluate to `NaN`, which `charCodeAt()` accepts as equivalent to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

As T.J. Crowder pointed out, [`String.prototype.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) takes an index as a parameter. The reason you're getting 97 all the time is (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)):

> if it [the parameter] is not a number, it defaults to 0.

So it always takes the first letter (with index 0), which is "a" and its char code is 97.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your string in an array (dumping) and map each character with its ascci code (transfarmation expected). This way, you would write it shortly in JS :

```js
var fillArray = str => str.split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt(0));
console.log(fillArray("bonjour le monde"));
```